# Сборка ibase.pro с QT 5.5 win32-msvc2010

Tags: qt, firebird, interbase, база-данных

Нужно собрать ibase.pro для того чтобы работать с СУБД firebird из QT.
Система: Windows 7 SP1 32 bit.
Установлено:

- QT 5.5.1-0 (msvc2010 32bit)
- Source components/ Essentials (5.5.1-0)
- Firebird 2.1.5 32 bit

Делаю по инструкции [с официального сайта](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qibase), только вместо

```
cd %QTDIR%\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/interbase/include" "LIBS+=-lfbclient" ibase.pro
```

делаю так:
создание библиотеки fbclient.dll в c:\windows\system32

```
C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\bin\instclient i f
```

затем это для сборки драйвера

```
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake INCLUDEPATH+='C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\include'" "LIBS+=-LC:\Windows\system32\fbclient.dll" ibase.pro
Project ERROR: Cannot load qmodule.pri!
Error processing project file: ibase.pro
```

До этого пытался собрать с QT 5.1 только для mingw32. В ходе попыток получилась команда, которая приведена выше. 
Путь к папке include дополнительно взят в одинарные кавычки, т.к. в пути есть пробел. -lfbclient тоже заменен, иначе ld не видел библиотеку.

Из-за [различий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038649/compiling-interbase-support-in-qt) в компиляторах (firebird собран с MSVS, а qt был с mingw) решил перейти на QT 5.5.1 ( с msvc2010).

Если выполнить с ключом **-d**, то получим

```
    C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+='C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\include'" "LIBS+=-LC:\Windows\system32\fbclient.dll" i base.pro -d 
DEBUG 1: Resetting dir to: C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase
DEBUG 1: visiting file C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf:1: evaluating test function "load"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf:1: calling built-in load(qt_build_config)
DEBUG 1: visiting file C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: NOT
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: evaluating test function "contains"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: calling built-in contains(QMAKE_INTERNAL_INCLUDED_FILES, .*qmodule\\.pri)
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: test function returned false
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: taking 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:13: QMAKE_QT_MODULE := C:/work/build/PADDING/mkspecs/qmodule.pri
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: NOT 
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: evaluating test function "exists"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: calling built-in exists(C:/work/build/PADDING/mkspecs/qmodule.pri)
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: test function returned false
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: OR
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: NOT
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: skipped test function "include"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: taking 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: evaluating test function "error"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: calling built-in error("Cannot load qmodule.pri!")
Project ERROR: Cannot load qmodule.pri!
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: aborting block, function status: error
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: finished 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: aborting block, status: error
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: finished 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: aborting block, status: error
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf:1: aborting block, function status: error
Error processing project file: ibase.pro
```

Такого файла

QMAKE_QT_MODULE := C:/work/build/PADDING/mkspecs/qmodule.pri

в системе нет, вместо него, я думаю, должен использоваться

```
c:\Qt\5.5\msvc2010\mkspecs\qmodule.pri
```

Значения путей в системных переменных Qt наводят на мысль что что-то не так сконфигурировалось:

```
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_INSTALL_DATA:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:C:/work/build/PADDING/doc
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:C:/work/build/PADDING/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:C:/work/build/PADDING/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:C:/work/build/PADDING/bin
QT_INSTALL_BINS:C:/work/build/PADDING/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:C:/work/build/PADDING/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:C:/work/build/PADDING/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:C:/work/build/PADDING/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:C:/work/build/PADDING/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:C:/work/build/PADDING/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:C:/work/build/PADDING/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:C:/work/build/PADDING/examples
QT_HOST_PREFIX:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_HOST_DATA:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_HOST_BINS:C:/work/build/PADDING/bin
QT_HOST_LIBS:C:/work/build/PADDING/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:win32-msvc2010
QMAKE_XSPEC:win32-msvc2010
QMAKE_VERSION:3.0
QT_VERSION:5.5.1
```

Что еще можно проверить? Пока мысли только о переустановке QT...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю чистая установка QT разрешила проблему. 
Итак ставим MS Visual Studio 2010 Express SP1 (SP1 обязательно), QT 5.1.1 (msvc2010), Src/Essentials.
Также должен быть Firebird. Я использовал версию 2.5.5 в zip архиве и распаковал её в C:\QT\firebird255_32. После распаковки потребовалось также сделать копию файла C:\QT\firebird255_32\lib\fbclient_ms.lib и назвать её 
C:\QT\firebird255_32\lib\gds32_ms.lib.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/QT/firebird255_32/include" "LIBS+=-LC:/QT/firebird255_32/lib" ibase.pro
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>nmake
```

Если все прошло успешно, то в папаке c:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\
появятся файлы:

qsqlibase.dll qsqlibase.exp qsqlibase.lib 
qsqlibased.dll qsqlibased.exp qsqlibased.ilk qsqlibased.lib qsqlibased.pdb

Которые нужно скопировать в папку c:\Qt\5.5\msvc2010\plugins\sqldrivers.

Поскольку основной задачей была имменно успешная компиляция, то эти библиотеки не проверялись в приложениях. Также нужно обратить внимание что используемая мной версия Firebird не устанавливалась в систему (возможно будут проблемы с переносом приложений).
[Здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post5231947.html) в тоже есть пример успешной сборки этого драйвера, причем даже комплятором mingw. Возможно и не обязательно было использовать именно msvc2010.